# Как работает формула поворота вектора на угол?

Tags: математика, векторы

Есть формула поворота вектора на угол:

```
Vector vector(x, y)
Angel angle
rotatedX = x * cos(angle) - y * sin(angle)
rotatedY = x * sin(angle) + y * cos(angle)
```

Не совсем понимаю, как появилась такая формула. Почему для X вычитается произведение синуса на У, а для У складываются?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Тут всё просто. Для начала рассмотрим более простую задачу: какие координаты будут у единичного вектора, который повёрнут относительно оси абсцисс на угол α? Ответ: (cos α, sin α). Это чуть ли не определение косинуса и синуса.

Что такое координаты? Это коэффициенты в разложении вектора по базису:

**r** = **i** cos α + **j** sin α

Здесь **r** - искомый вектор, **i** и **j** - базисные вектора.

[image]

Таким образом, поворачивать базисный вектор в ортонормированном базисе очень просто.

---

Теперь вспомним, что нам надо повернуть не базисный вектор, а указанный. Обозначим его буквой **v**. Так вот, повернуть его очень просто: надо сделать его базисным! Точнее, надо построить ортонормированный базис с его участием. В конце концов, ортонормированный базис на плоскости - это всего лишь два перпендикулярных вектора одинаковой длины, и один из них у нас уже есть.

Чтобы найти второй вектор, надо повернуть вектор **v** на 90 градусов. Это делается куда проще, чем поворот на произвольный угол:

[image]

Как видно, если у вектора **v** координаты были (x, y) - то у перпендикулярного вектора **u** координаты будут (-y, x). Можете проверить сами - это верно для любого квадранта. И обратите ещё раз внимание на разные знаки у координат: именно отсюда в дальнейшем возникнет интересующее вас несоответствие.

---

И так, у нас есть ортонормированный базис, у нас если формула поворота базисного вектора, и нам надо его повернуть:

[image]

Кажется, всё готово для получения ответа. Получаем формулу в векторном виде:

**r** = **v** cos α + **u** sin α

Теперь подставим в формулу координаты обоих векторов и...

r<sub>x</sub> = x cos α - y sin α

r<sub>y</sub> = y cos α + x sin α

Comment: Спасибо, теперь понял)

Answer (score 2):

Да все просто... Смотрите на картинку. x' и y' — в повернутой на угол α системе координат.

Уравнения выписаны справа. Раскрываете тригонометрию — косинус и синус разности, и подставляете значения синусов и косинусов β из первого и третьего уравнений. Так и получите уравнения, связывающие координаты в одной и другой системе координат...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]