# Вычислить XY координаты вершины треугольника, зная длинны всех сторон

Tags: алгоритм, математика, геометрия

есть упрошенная формула определения координаты вершины треугольника, если основание треугольника расположено на оси X. (нужно для определения положения при навигации, используя всего 2 точки привязки, вместо 3)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
/// <summary>
/// Определение координат вершины треугольника C.
/// по закону косинусов и теореме пифагора можно вычислить позицию тега. 
/// Треугольник задан вершинами ABC
/// A находится в начале координат (0,0)
/// B вдоль оси X, (var, 0)
/// </summary>
/// <param name="a">длина стороны CB - расстояние от тега C до якоря B</param>
/// <param name="b">длина стороны CA - расстояние от тега C до якоря A (ОТРЕЗОК ВЫХОДЯЩИЙ ИЗ НАЧАЛА КООРДИНАТ - A (0,0))</param>
/// <param name="c">длина стороны AB - расстояние между якорями A и B</param>
/// 
/// <returns></returns>
public static (double x, double y)  CalculatePosition(double a, double b, double c)
{
    var cosA= (b*b + c*c - a*a)/(2*b*c);
    var x = b * cosA;
    var y = b * Math.Sqrt(1 - cosA * cosA);
    return (Math.Round(x, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero), Math.Round(y, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
}

A (0,0)
B (70,0)
C (x,y)
c= 70
b=58
a= 37

C (x,y) = 50,30
```

А если вершина B находится не на оси Х?
Входные данные для формулы все те же, это длинны сторон (abc), но точка B теперь имеет координаты B (65,25). Точку  A (0,0) оставим в начале координат
И нужно все также определить координаты точки С.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Зачем `Math.Round`?

Comment: Сделайте что-нибудь с оформлением, у вас часть условия картинкой

Comment: Я верно понимаю что c b a известны в обоих случаях? тогда стройте еще один треугольник ABY где Y - перпендикуляр из B к оси X.....

Comment: c b a  известны, как раз таки "c" и можно вычислить через пифагора, зная координаты точки "B".Не понял про перпендикуляр к оси Х, что мне это даст? То есть будет проекция точки B на ось Х и это даст новое расстояние "с"?

Comment: Главный вопрос в том, есть ли у нас координаты точки B, помимо (a,b,c). Если да, то эта другая функция и b нам не обязательно. Если нет, то и решения нет.

Comment: Ну, Если есть координаты двух точек, то расстояние между ними вычисляется :) А дальше - два уравнения на расстояние от (x,y) до А и до В - и все, решаемо на уровне квадратных уравнений. Громоздко, да, но - решаемо.

Comment: Координата точек А, B известны и известны все длинны сторон.

Comment: не представляю как проверить формулу Harry) выраженную в алгоритме на СИ подобном языке программирования

Comment: @Aldmi проверяют математическую запись, а на языке реализуют вычисление формулы вот прямо так: `(-a*a*bx-sqrt(-by*by*(a*a*a*a-...)/(2*(...))`   и т.д.

Comment: а если в формуле +- стоит, например перед корнем?

Comment: @Aldmi Два решения - вершина C может быть ниже AB или выше. У себя в функции вы это игнорируете, используя только положительное значение sqrt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ещё один способ:
-раз уж у вас есть функция для нахождения координат, когда B на оси - грешно её не использовать ещё раз. Найдите  координаты `сx,сy`, как и ранее, как если бы B была на оси, используя длины сторон, а затем поверните их на угол между AB и осью OX. Для поворота нужны косинус и синус этого угла, их выразить из заданных величин нетрудно:

```
cosa = B.x / c
sina = B.y / c
//а теперь повернём:
C.x = cx * cosa - cy * sina
C.y = cx * sina + cy * cosa
```

Comment: Отлично, спасибо большой, не мог догадается как повернуть)

Comment: Что-то много углов как-то. Достаточно повернуть вектор AB на угол который уже вычислен автором, и изменить его длину. Угол между AB и осью абсцисс тут лишний.

Comment: @Pavel Mayorov Да, тоже вариант, вычислительно он такой же.

Answer (score 2):

Раз уж вы нашли косинус и синус угла в треугольнике - дальше вы можете просто [повернуть на этот угол](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1409394/178779) вектор одной из сторон и получить направление второй стороны, а дальше нужно лишь изменить длину вектора.

Но есть и решение в векторах, вообще без тригонометрии.

---

Рассмотрим задачу в общем виде: у нас заданы вершины A и B, нам надо найти третью вершину треугольника С зная прилежащие к ней стороны - AC=a и BC=b соответственно. Построим окружности нужных радиусов с центрами в точках A и B, и тогда точка C как раз будет на их пересечении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Обозначим через **rA**, **rB** и **rC** радиус-векторы точек. Тогда получаем следующую систему уравнений:

```
(rC-rA)² = a²
(rC-rB)² = b²
```

Решив её относительно **rC** можно получить ответ. Для решения первым делом вычтем одно уравнение из другого, чтобы избавиться от квадрата **rC**:

```
(rC-rA)² - (rC-rB)² = a² - b²
(rC² - 2rCrA + rA²) - (rC² - 2rCrB + rB²) = a² - b²
2rC(rB-rA) + rA² - rB² = a² - b²
2rC(rB-rA) = a² - b² - (rA² - rB²)
```

У нас получилось, внезапно или не очень, уравнение прямой в одном из своих форм. Этой прямой по построению принадлежат точки C и C' - значит, это уравнение прямой CC'. Кстати, разности **rB** - **rA** будет в дальнейшем встречаться часто, поэтому обозначим её как **AB** (потому что это и есть вектор стороны AB).

В принципе, на этом этапе можно перейти от векторного вида к координатному, выразить через это уравнение переменную **y** через **x** или наоборот, подставить в любое уравнение окружности и решить обыкновенное квадратное уравнение. Однако, любого кто так попытается сделать, ожидает засада под названием "сингулярность": если прямая CC' вертикальная, то при попытке выразить **y** через **x** в формуле будет деление на ноль, а если она горизонтальная - деление на ноль будет при попытке выразить **x** через **y**.

Можно было бы просто разобрать два случая, но есть вариант лучше. Для этого надо перейти к параметрическому виду уравнения прямой СС'. Напомню, что параметрический вид уравнения прямой выглядит вот так:

```
r = r0 + t u
```

Чтобы получить параметрическое уравнение прямой, нужно знать направляющий вектор и любую точку на этой прямой. Точки C и С' мы узнать не можем (точнее можем, но если узнаем - задача будет уже решена), поэтому попытаемся найти точку пересечения прямых CC' и AB.

Это сделать не так сложно как кажется, потому что у нас есть уравнение прямой CC' и мы можем составить параметрическое уравнение прямой AB:

```
r = rA + tAB
2r·AB = a² - b² - (rA² - rB²)
```

Подставим первое уравнение во второе и решим его относительно переменной **t**:

```
2(rA + tAB)·AB = a² - b² - (rA² - rB²)

2rA·AB + 2t AB² = a² - b² - (rA² - rB²)

t = (a² - b² - rA² + rB² - 2rA·AB) / 2AB²

t = (a² - b² - rA² + rB² + 2rA² - 2rA·rB) / 2AB²

t = (a² - b² + rA² + rB² - 2rA·rB) / 2AB²

t = (a² - b² + (rA - rB)²) / 2AB²

t = (a² - b² + AB²) / 2AB²
```

Осталось подставить эту переменную обратно в параметрическое уравнение:

```
t = (a² - b² + AB²) / 2AB²
r0 = rA + tAB
```

Формула выглядит страшно, но не имеет сингулярностей пока A и B - разные точки. Даже в случае некорректных начальных данных у тут будет какое-то решение.

Кстати, для проверки корректности формулы можно подставить сюда вырожденные треугольники: при a=0, b=AB точка r0 окажется равна rA; а при a=AB, b=0 точка r0 окажется равна rB. Пока всё нормально.

И так, у нас есть точка **r0**, осталось найти направляющий вектор прямой CC'. Ну, это тоже просто: надо лишь взять вектор **AB** и повернуть его на прямой угол в любую сторону. Это делается тоже просто, если вектор **AB** был с координатами (xB - xA, yB - yA) - то повёрнутый будет с координатами (-yB + yA, xB - xA). Почему так - объясняется по ссылке, которую я уже приводил ранее. Обозначим его через **AB^**.

Ну, теперь у нас есть параметрическое уравнение прямой CC' и уравнение одной из окружностей, осталось их пересечь и мы найдём точки C и C'.

```
rC = r0 + k AB^
(rC-rA)² = a²
```

И снова мы можем просто подставить одно уравнение в другое (вот почему я так люблю параметрические уравнения прямых в задачах на геометрию!):

```
(r0-rA + k AB^)² = a²

k² AB^² + 2k AB^ (r0-rA) + (r0-rA)² - a² = 0
```

Тут есть и дальнейшие упрощения: вектор **r0**-**rA** сонаправлен **AB**, а потому при умножении на **AB^** будет чистый ноль, можно и не считать. Кстати, длина вектора **AB^** равна длине вектора **AB**, что тоже позволяет чуть упростить формулу.

Суммируя всё что написано выше, получаем следующую систему уравнений:

```
t = (a² - b² + AB²) / 2AB²
k² AB² = a² - t² AB²
r0 = rA + t AB
rC = r0 + k AB^
```

Осталось решить примитивное квадратное уравнение:

```
t = (a² - b² + AB²) / 2AB²
k = ± sqrt(a² / AB² - t²)
rC = rA + t AB + k AB^
```

Дальше осталось перейти от векторов к координатам и решение готово.

Comment: Спасибо) есть что по изучать из вашего поста.)

Answer (score 1):

Если вершина A лежит в начале координат, вершина B в точке (x_b,y_b), а расстояния |CA| = b и |CB| = a, то, если Wolfram не врет, координаты двух точек C следующие:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если есть координаты двух точек, то расстояние между ними вычисляется :) А дальше - два уравнения на расстояние от (x,y) до А и до В - и все, решаемо на уровне квадратных уравнений. Громоздко, да, но - решаемо.

```
x^2+y^2==b^2
(x-x_b)^2+(y-y_b)^2==a^2
```

Собственно, вот и все. Ответ - см. выше.

А вот что делать, если

```
x_b^2 + y_b^2 != c^2
```

(расстояние |AB| не равно c) — тут уж думайте сами...

Comment: Кто там поставил минус - Wolfram ошибся? Тогда приведите правильный ответ, pls...

Comment: Объяснение-то где?

Comment: @PavelMayorov Было в комментарии. Теперь в ответе :)

Comment: ...рисуем остаток совы.